# rounded corners while extending subview beyond superview's bounds

Tags: ios, animation, core-animation, uiviewanimation, cornerradius

I'm designing a specific animation. The image scales beyond bounds, shrinks to appropriate size and than falls down. You can see what I got so far is this video: https://vid.me/i1bx.

The effect I would like to achieve is that the first imageView (the grey one) has rounded corners. Setting the **cornerRadius** and **clipsToBounds** of first imageView to true does that, but disables the scaling effect of second imageView(firstScaleImageView) beyond first imageView's bounds.

Is it possible to have rounded corners and also be capable of expanding the imageView beyond superviews's bounds?

This is my code:

```
   @IBAction func goButtonpressed(sender: UIButton) {
        firstScaleImageView = UIImageView(frame: bounceFrame)
        firstScaleImageView.image = UIImage(named: "1")
        firstScaleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformScale(firstScaleImageView.transform, 0, 0)
        firstImageView.addSubview(firstScaleImageView)

        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.4, delay: 0, usingSpringWithDamping: 0.7, initialSpringVelocity: 10, options: UIViewAnimationOptions.CurveLinear, animations: {
            self.firstScaleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformIdentity
            }, completion: {_ in
                self.firstImageView.clipsToBounds = true
        })
    }
    @IBAction func backButtonPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.3, animations: {
            self.firstScaleImageView.transform = CGAffineTransformTranslate(self.firstScaleImageView.transform, 0,  self.firstImageView.frame.height)
            }, completion: {_ in
                self.firstImageView.clipsToBounds = false
                self.firstScaleImageView.removeFromSuperview()
        })
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to set `clipsToBounds` to `false` (I don't think you need it for the **corner radius**).

Comment: it's either clipsToBounds or masksToBounds that need to be true. Both don't solve the problem.  Note that when the second imageView drops, clipsToBounds must be true. Don't know any other way

Comment: `clipsToBounds` will _clip_ all the subviews... and by the way, you can just use 2 different `UIImageView`'s wrapped by a `UIView`, who's `clipsToBounds` would be `NO` while animation is in progress and `YES` when finishes, then "drop" the second `imageView` down.